# Data driven testing and assertions

Tags: python, data-driven-tests

From the below code if the value of "suminsured" and "tenure" differs for every different data set, how to put assertion for variable dataset?

```
response = requests.post(url, json= plan1A1C(suminsured, tenure),)
json_response = response.json()

assert int(json_response[0]['premium']) == int(100000)
assert int(json_response[0]['term']) == int(1)
```

Now for 1 data set, suminsured = 100000 and tenure = 1, for another data set, it will be different. like this if there are 10 data sets, how to manage assertions?

Comment: I assume for another data set different url being fetched if so use same code as above for another url and add assertions again for different data. To avoid duplicating request and assertions, create mapping of key =url value =data to assert with and apply for loop.

Comment: For another dataset, URL will be same but the Json body will be different. I just need to use some technique so that I can use assertions over variable data set

Comment: this might help https://github.com/rugleb/JsonCompare , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compare-json-objects-regardless-of-order-in-python/